# Are there any non-rainbow markets to buy unicoins in?

Tags: support, unicoins

I currently have gnomes farming Unicoins as part of my plan of world domination. Unfortunately, I'm encountering what one might call "liquidity issues". I'm concerned that once I've amassed a significant quantity of Unicoins that the currency might be devalued.

To mitigate this risk, I need an exit strategy. The best way I can think of is to find some <strike>sorry saps</strike> willing buyers to sell my coins to. I've also noticed minor technical glitches with existing Unicoin transfer systems and want to keep my options open.

Obviously there's no black markets in Unicorn Land, but I'm looking for something off-rainbow. Are there alternative markets for Unicoins?

Comment: +1 for "off-rainbow" :)

Answer (score 2):

Unicoins, like unicorns (and some people) are worth their weight in gold. But nobody tells you that they are actually **made** of gold.

These unicoins can be melted down into gold bricks to be sold off-rainbow. However, watch out for fake unicoins and fake unicoin bricks. You can tell they are fake because they smell like science.

Comment: So fool's unicoins? I didn't know that was a concern. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

I'll buy them all, please contact me after two days to see how many Unicoins you have.